# SkyDrive authentication doesn't work in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, onedrive, live-sdk

I'm developing Windows Store App and I want to use `LiveSDK` to upload some file on `SkyDrive`. But I'm getting some problem. I have found some [sample SkyDrive App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141) which work correct and I get some code which should make authentication to Live account:

```
var scopes = new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive", "wl.skydrive_update" };  
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    this.session = authResult.Session;
}
```

But second line of this code throw an **exception**:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

So I have search for some solution and I find [this article](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/09/26/windows-8-connecting-to-live-skydrive.aspx). Then I register my app on my `developer dashboard`, make all instruction and associate my app with app from my dashboard. But it doesn't change anything.

What can I do to my App start work with my Live Account?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can give me the project then it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, In my `Package.appxmanifest` I have got unchecked `Internet` in my capabilitie. When I check it everything goes correct.

**@Xyroid** your comment help me with it I create new project which run correct and then I have compared both `appxmanifests` Thanks!